# Dice game strategy

Tags: dice, combinatorial-game-theory

So, I have to find a solution to this seemingly simple dice game, but I am not sure if my answer is the right one. The game goes as follows:

> There are two dice which each have a different color. You predict the outcome of both dice and throw them. If:
>
> 1. you correctly predict both numbers on both dice, you get 10 points;
> 2. you predict the correct numbers, but they are the wrong color, you get 5 points;
> 3. you only predict one color and number correctly, you get 2 points.
>
> What is the best strategy to choose the numbers?

My logic is that I look at which numbers summed up show up most frequently and then try to predict them, since every game is independent and the last outcome doesn't say anything about the next one. Since 7 has a 16.6% probability to show up, try with combinations like $1-6$, $2-5$, $3-4$, $4-3$, $5-2$, $6-1$. Is there a better way to go about it?

EDIT: Forgot to add, only the highest points are paid out. So if you predict $(1,1)$ and get that, you would get 10 points and not 5 or 2, or all of them.

Comment: Each ordered pair is equally likely.  Doubles, like $(1,1)$ can not get you $5$ points hence should be avoided.  The others are all equivalent.

Comment: Okay, but doubles like (1,1) do give you 10 points.

Comment: Sure, but why forego the chance of getting the $5$?  It doesn't diminish your chance of getting $10$.  What i mean is:  if you guess $(1,2)$ then you win $10$ if it comes up $(1,2)$, you win $5$ if it comes up $(2,1)$ and you win $2$if it comes up $(2,*)$ or $(*,1)$ for $*\in \{3,4,5,6\}$. If you guess $(1,1)$ then you get $10$ for $(1,1)$ and $2$ for $(1,*)$ or $(*,1)$  for $*\in \{2,3,4,5,6\}$ so it is better to go with $(1,2)$.

Comment: Ah, it's not as clear as I said as there are two more $2$ point chances if you guess $(1,1)$.  So you need to compute the expected gain of each guess.

Comment: Well, as said, only the highest payouts get paid, not all. I don't see any clear pattern on how to tackle this. My best guess is that it's random.

Comment: i don't understand that comment.  My breakdown assumed you only got one of the payouts.  (N.B. my original claim was correct, since $2\times 2<5$.  Thus the two small payouts are still less then the one big one).

Comment: Lulu already nailed it, so I won't make this an answer. The items 1 and 3 are equal whether you choose different or same numbers. Item 2 can be gotten only if you choose different numbers. It doesn't matter what the numbers are, because the scoring only cares about if they are same or not.